# Windows key keeps getting "stuck"

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I'm using the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key quite often in my daily work and it keeps getting "stuck".

I tried two keyboards (One USB and one PS/2)
I tried to mess with the `Sticky Keys` definitions.

Eventually, when it happens - pressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key a single press releases the "lock" and solves the problem.

It happens several times a day - so it is quite annoying. Especially when I start typing and multiple windows start to open or the desktop appears suddenly.

Any idea why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Physically stuck or Windows is seeing it as permenantly 'on'

Comment: If it was Physically stuck I would have replaced it :) - it is acting as if it is permanently 'on'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered the problem on my laptop, my desktop and my work desktop, so it's obviously not the keyboard (or it's all three).  I usually see it when I'm using remote desktop.

I've found a [thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/cbaae74e-8311-4a46-a842-31dcdd6878dc/) suggesting it's a bug related to using Win+L to lock your screen and should be fixed in Vista SP-1, but obviously, it's not.

I've found that just pressing the windows key once seems to resolve it for me, until it happens again.

Comment: This is the exact phenomenon I'm having - I was hoping to get a solution that does not require me to click on the Windows key every once in a while ...

Comment: But my problem is not as mentioned in that thread. My problem persists outside of the RDP - it is acting like StickyKeys, but StickyKeys is disabled

Comment: The solution of pressing the key again is currently the only one I found :(. Let me know if you ever find something better ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need StickyKeys, try [disabling it](http://www.google.com/search?q=disable+stickykeys+windows+7) and see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an end-user, this method helped me. I don't think she used the hotkey before.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5937-windows-key-shortcuts-enable-disable.html

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better if you included the details in your answer as links may be broken in the future.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you type <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> (at least, on my keyboard and Windows install).  Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> gets me out of this mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Win+Alt` three times to fix it. It works on my laptop.

As @scott mentioned, when you use `Win+L` to lock your PC, the bug may occur.

It's hard to imagine that in 2022, win11 still has this bug.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1118894)