# Windows 7, keys opening unwanted things

Tags: windows-7

When I turned on my computer this morning every time I press some specific keys unwanted things happen, for example, "l" goes to the switch user page, "p" shows me the choose monitor window or "e" opens My Computer, and other things!

Also every minute or so the start button gets activated!

I wanted to know how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a different keyboard....then tell us whether that fixed it.

Comment: I did, the problem persists!

Comment: What do you mean by when you “turned it on”? Had you shut it down last time or just put it in standby/sleep (e.g., closed the laptop lid)? jdh is correct that the `⊞ Win` key is definitely stuck being toggled. Is it a laptop or desktop?

Comment: Jdh was correct, there was a physical problem with the windows key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keys you mention are Windows-key hotkey combinations. (ex windows+E = Explorer).
[Other threads](https://superuser.com/questions/290498/windows-key-keeps-getting-stuck) mention the windows key getting stuck, either logically or physically.
They mention being able to toggle the effect off by just hitting the windows key once.

If this is happening after every reboot, perhaps something that is loaded during startup (driver or script) has toggled the windows key into this stuck mode. You can experiment by booting to safe mode to see if avoiding the regular startup is causing this problem or if its a physical keyboard problem.